# Retrieving current architecture for RPM

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm automating RPM package building with `rpmbuild`. The files end up in the architecture subdirectory under `RPMS`.

Question - how do I retrieve, from a shell script, the architecture name of the host that RPM is using? It's not the same as `arch` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc` that translates known OS-level architecture names into canonical RPM architecture names. The following shell script does the job for me:

```
ARCH=`arch`
# OS-level architecture name, like 'i686'

ARCH=`cat /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc | grep "buildarchtranslate: $ARCH" | cut -c21-`
# returns the translate line as "arch-from: arch-to"

ARCH=${ARCH/#*: /}
# strips the prefix up to colon and following space, returns arch-to.
# Assumes just one space after colon. If not, more regex magic is needed.
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like

```sh
rpm --eval '%{_arch}'
```

does the trick:

```
$ rpm --eval '%{_arch}'
x86_64

$ rpm --target 'SPARC64' --eval '%{_arch}'
sparc64
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Redefine %_build_name_fmt in ~/.rpmmacros.

Comment: The architecture is also a part of the generated file name, by convention. And I want it that way. So I'd rather retrieve the architecture than change the file name format.